# Solspace: User - Total Entries showing as 0 for user

Tags: solspace-user

I am running Solspace User 3.5.3 on EE 2.9.2 and have a discrepancy with the total number of entries shown for a user.

When I am logged in as admin for the site and I go to my profile in user_main, it says I have a total of 0 entries. However it also has a link to the page that displays all my entries and there are 19 pages worth of entries.

The code for this section is:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
<strong>Total Entries:</strong> &nbsp; 
{if last_entry_date == "0"}
This user has not published any entries yet.
{if:else}
{total_entries} &nbsp; <i>(last published: {last_entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"})</i>
{/if}
&nbsp; <a href="{path='user_main/user_entries'}/{member_id}/">view all &rarr;</a>
</li>
```

The same problem is evident on the user_entries page where despite the fact that there are 19 pages of entries, the total_count shows as 0.

[image]

The code:

```
<h2 style="margin-bottom:20px;">{exp:user:stats member_id="{segment_3}" limit="1"}{if logged_in_member_id == "{segment_3}"}My{if:else}{screen_name}'s{/if} Entries <span class="label label-warning">{total_entries}{/exp:user:stats}</span></h2>
```

Clearly {total_entries} is having a bad day.

Comment: I have a site with EE 2.9.2 and User 3.5.0 ... And your code worked fine for me. Do you have that block of code inside of any other EE loops?

Comment: No. This is directly from the Solspace provided templates.

Comment: Random suggestion.. Turn in php on input, and do this: <?php $t = "{segment_3}"; var_dump($t); ?> and see if you get a weird looking result.

Comment: Also, if you hard code a value instead of segment_3, do you get the expected results?

Comment: I get the following output:   string(0) "" and the results are the same if I hard code the member id.

Comment: Hrm, if the results are the same when you hard code a member id you know has entries, this could be an addon conflict. And I actually meant do that var_dump with php on output.

Comment: Are the entries for this user in a status other than "Open", expired, future dates, etc? :)

Comment: The entries are all in the 'Open' status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been some sort of issue with EE's stats being up to date for channel entry data. I ran the recount stats utility on your site and the numbers seem to be correct now. :)